# Empty form doesn't show on the page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-authentication

I am building custom user authentification logic on my site. I created `MyUser`model than created form

```
from django import forms                                     
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,UserChangeForm
from .models import MyUser

classCustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
       model = MyUser
       fields = ('email',)
```

Than in project level urls.py file i added the following path

```
 urlpatterns =[ 
 path('login/',include('authorization.urls'),]
```

Than in `authorization/urls.py` i created

```
from django.urls import path                                  
from .views import login_form                                                                                            
urlpatterns =
[path(' ',login_form,name='login_form'),]
```

In my view file i have the following method which if request == GET should return empty form and if form is_valid() it's redirect to another page

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect               
from django.shortcuts import render                           
from .form import UserCreationForm

def login_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data('email')
            password = form.cleaned_data('password')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank/')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'registration/log.html',{'form':form})
```

And last piece is `log.html`

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}                             
<form action="{% url 'login_form' %}" method="post">              
{% csrf_token %}
 {{ form }}                                
<input type="submit" value="Submit">                         
</form>
```

But when i run server and open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/`
I haven't anything no exceptions and haven't empty form itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending the `main/base.html` template in your `log.html` file; However, you did not include any `{% blcok xxx %}` there.

So it will omit the entire *custom* html inside the `log.html`.

Basically, if you have something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

in your **base.html**, then you should have the following for your `log.html`:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}  

{% block content %}              
    <form action="{% url 'login_form' %}" method="post">              
    {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}                                
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">                         
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```